# Presented UIHostingController navigation bar with custom left button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am presenting a `UIHostingController` with `modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`, so I want a button in the top left corner to dismiss it when it presents.  I tried adding:

```
navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back")
```

But it doesn't even show up on the navigation bar.

Here is a minimal version of my code. I have RootView, which has a button, and when pressed, it presents PresentedViewController.  The navigation bar title shows up on PresentedViewController but not the leftBarButtonItem:

```
class ViewController: UIHostingController<RootView> {
  
  let viewModel: RootViewModel
  
  @MainActor @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.viewModel = RootViewModel()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder, rootView: RootView(viewModel: viewModel))
  }
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    viewModel.onPressed = { [weak self] in
      guard let self = self else { return }
      let vc = PresentedViewController()
      let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
      navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
      self.navigationController?.present(navController, animated: true)
    }
  }
}

struct RootView: View {
  let viewModel: RootViewModel
  
  var body: some View {
    Button("Button") {
      viewModel.onPressed?()
    }
  }
}

class RootViewModel {
  var onPressed: (() -> Void)? = nil
}

class PresentedViewController: UIHostingController<PresentedView> {
  init() {
    super.init(rootView: PresentedView())
    self.title = "Presented screen title"
  }
  
  @MainActor @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back")
  }
}

struct PresentedView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Presented screen")
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of presented screen]

Comment: You should configure `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` on your `PresentedViewController`, not on the navigation controller itself. Each view controller within a navigation stack has its own button configurations and the navigation controller will show the buttons for the top view controller.